# Spliting a number range

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle19c

I have 2 requirements, where 1. split a number range into a fix set of ranges, and 2. I have to find and split a smaller range from a bigger set. Requirement 1. splitting 1 to 10000 in set of 1000, like 1 to 1000, 1001 to 2000 and so on. Requirement 2, Finding and splitting any given range like 101 to 200 from 1 to 10000, so that I can have 1-100, 101-200, 201-10000. Bigger range 1-10000 is present in database. But i'm having difficulty in splitting range as per requirement 2

I managed to solve 1st requirement by using hierarchical query as below

```
with t as (select 1 DN_from, 10000 DN_to from duat)
select DN_from+((level-1)*1000) DN_from, least(DN_from+((level-1)*1000)+999,DN_to) DN_to from t connect by DN_from+((level-1)*1000) <= DN_to;
```

For 2nd requirement for finding a bigger range from batabase which contains 101 to 200, i used below query,
`select DN_from, DN_to from table1 where DN_from <= 200 and DN_to >= 100`.
But i am stuck in splitting range as per requirement 2. Need suggestion in this regard.

Edit:
Table contains a code and From and To ranges

```
Code ~  Dn_from  ~ Dn_to
A     ~ 1        ~  10000
A     ~ 10001    ~ 20000
A     ~ 20001    ~ 30000
B     ~  1       ~  10000
B     ~ 10001    ~ 20000
```

User will enter code A and any range example 101 to 200. Now I have to find then range which contains 101-200 (in above table it's first record) and split it and save in table like below (expected output).

```
Code  ~ Dn_from   ~ Dn_to
A     ~  1        ~  100
A     ~  101      ~  200 --user input range 
A     ~ 201       ~ 10000
```

if range given is 1 to 100, then split will be like below

```
Code  ~ Dn_from   ~ Dn_to
A     ~  1        ~  100
A     ~  101      ~  10000
```

if range given is 1000 to 10000, then split will be like below

```
Code  ~ Dn_from   ~ Dn_to
A     ~  1        ~  999
A     ~  1000      ~  10000
```

if range given is 1 to 1, then split will be like below

```
Code  ~ Dn_from   ~ Dn_to
A     ~  1        ~  1
A     ~  2        ~  10000
```

I am able to find range from table with follwing query,
`select DN_from, DN_to from table1 where code='A' and DN_from <= 200 and DN_to >= 100;`. I am not able to split as per expected output.

Comment: Please be more clear. What data is in the database and what output are you expecting. You're describing your problem as if everyone can see you data but... nope. Please provide sample data and table definition (as scripts not screenshots)

Comment: @KoenLostrie I have edited the question to give more clarity. Please let me know if any more information required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility. Note that I added a primary key column to the table, that is used for joining in the merge statement.

```
create table split_range_test (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint test_table_id_pk primary key,
    code                           varchar2(100 char),
    dn_from                        number,
    dn_to                          number
);


INSERT INTO split_range_test(code,dn_from,dn_to) VALUES ('A',1001,2000);
INSERT INTO split_range_test(code,dn_from,dn_to) VALUES ('B',1,1000);
INSERT INTO split_range_test(code,dn_from,dn_to) VALUES ('B',2001,3000);

select * from split_range_test;


MERGE INTO split_range_test t_old
  USING
  (
    WITH primary_row (code, id, dn_from,dn_to) AS
    (
      SELECT code, id, 100 + 1 ,200 FROM split_range_test WHERE 100 > dn_from AND 200 < dn_to AND code = 'A'
    ),
    prev_row (code, id, dn_from,dn_to) AS
    (
      SELECT p.code, NULL, t.dn_from,100 FROM split_range_test t JOIN primary_row p ON t.id = p.id 
    ),
    next_row (code, id, dn_from,dn_to) AS
    (
      SELECT p.code, NULL, 200 + 1 ,t.dn_to FROM split_range_test t JOIN primary_row p ON t.id = p.id 
    )
    SELECT * FROM primary_row
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM prev_row
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM next_row
  ) t_new
  ON (t_old.id = t_new.id)
WHEN MATCHED
  THEN UPDATE 
    SET t_old.dn_from = t_new.dn_from,
        t_old.dn_to = t_new.dn_to
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (t_old.code,t_old.dn_from,t_old.dn_to)
     VALUES (t_new.code,t_new.dn_from,t_new.dn_to);


select * from split_range_test;

        ID CODE        DN_FROM      DN_TO
---------- -------- ---------- ----------
         1 A              1001       2000
         2 A               101        200
         3 B              2001       3000
         5 A                 1        100
         6 A               201       1000
```